# Display logs from multiple scripts on command line

Tags: command-line, logs

I'm running some node and perl scripts repeatedly and want to see the logs on the command line.
I tried writing logs to a corresponding file and following all log files with `tail -f *.log` but I don't like the way it's displayed.
Is there a way to see all logs but prefixed with the scripts name like:

```
node_script1 "starting"
perl_script1 "requesting api"
node_script2 "found ..."
node_script1 "finishing"
```

Please let me know if you have any recommendations.

Comment: If all programs write to the same file and they don't leave any identification in them there is no way to tell them appart (other than you knowing beforehand which messages came from where). The ideal thing to do is to configure different files or change the programs to include the prefixes you put as examples. I very doubt any software can tell the difference.

Comment: Every program is writing to a different file so that shouldnt be an issue. I just need a way to display everything at the same time properly. Unfortunately i can't change the programs to include a prefix.